# ActiveMQ, KahaDB, Web console and memory usage

Tags: java, activemq-classic, hawtio

I am using ActiveMQ 5.8.0, setup to persist messages with KahaDB. I am having trouble with ActiveMQ using a ridiculous amount of memory for a fairly simple operation.

I have set the wrapper heap space (Xmx) to 1536m, and the broker system memory to 1024m. Upon starting ActiveMQ, it uses a fair amount of memory, around 100MB. Then, when I open the ActiveMQ console, and try to access an error-queue with 700 messages, strange things starts to happen. The memory usage goes up. And up. And up. Until it stopes at around 1,5GB, but still it is not showing the queue. Then it stays there for a few minutes, until it fails with a outofmemoryerror for java  heap space (at least it did with a bit lower xmx-memory, now it just waits for several minutes). The messages are small, with no payload and just a couple of user-defined header properites. There is no way 700 of these messages can account for 1400MB of memory.

I also have access to another ActiveMQ instance. This is 5.7.0, set up to use a MSSQL-database for persistence. Here, I can open a queue with 50000 pending messages, showing 3000 of them in the webconsole in about 10 seconds.

When I try to connect with HawtIO instead of the ActiveMQ console, I do not see the insane rise in memory use, though still queue contents are really slow to view, and some queues (with 1000 somewhat larger messages) I am unable to view the contents of. Actually, when checking a bit more in different environments (dev/test), I see that an error queue that won't show it's contents in the dev-environment (with 1200 messages) will be shown in the test environment (with 1900 messages). This makes no sense..

Does anyone know what could cause the web console of ActiveMQ 5.8.0 to eat through all the memory? And why am I unable to see the contents of a relatively small queue, even when using HawtIO? I consider this to be some of the core functionality of ActiveMQ, and in that respected I am quite shocked at how poorly this actually works..

Comment: That is odd.  I'm assuming you've bumped the max browsable messages from the default (400) given that you can browse 3000 at a time?  If so, can you try to revert back to the default and see if this occurs still? With the size o your messages, I wouldn't expect the message to be an issue, but I have a similar set up without the issues you are having.

Comment: Strangely, in the 5.7.0 that was working fairly good, the number of shown messages was increased by 200 on each refresh of the queue-browser. I did it enough times to make sure that it could handle a large amount of messages, and stopped at around 3000. I'm guessing that this is a feature, though strange.. On the 5.8.0-version I can barely show 100 messages, so don't think the max browsable messages is the problem here..

Comment: If I remember correctly, there were some JIRAs that were fixed in 5.9.0 (5.9.1?) about unreasonable memory usage when browsing queues.  Have you checked the JIRA to make sure that your issue isn't a known one that's been fixed in a more-recent version?

Comment: I haven't checked Jira, but I've advised my client to upgrade ActiveMQ to a newer version, hopefully this will fix the problem.